# What all ways are there to print a string in python and which one is the most efficient?

Tags: python, text, printing, echo, stdout

There are several ways to print strings in python, using the print statement, StringIO(), and echoing in cmd. What all methods exist, and which ones are best in which cases? Which are the fastest? Which are simplest?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the methods to print a string in python, along with their speeds:

1.
Method: `print('Hello world!')`

Time: 3.472566604614258e-05

2.
Method: `os.system("echo 'Hello world!'")`

Time: 0.0050920481681823735

3.
Method: `sys.stdout.write('Hello world!\n')`

Time: 0.00018532516956329347

We observe that method 1 is the fastest.

The code used to calculate the time:

```
import time
import sys
import os

listf = []
for i in range(10000):
    start = time.time()
    print_function_to_be_timed('Hello world!')
    stop = time.time()
    listf.append((stop-start))
print(sum(listf) / len(listf))
```

Comment: The code showing how you arrived at these numbers might be interesting.

Comment: Isn't 3.472566604614258e-05 < 0.00018532516956329347, making Method 1 faster than Method 3 ?

Comment: Yeah, method one is the fastest. I corrected it.

Comment: @TomDalton The code is a basic timer. I was getting different values so I calculated it several times and found the mean. I edited the answer to provide the code.